# Walking a .NET callstack using native C++

Tags: .net, c++, callstack

Is there a way to walk a .NET callstack using native c++?
I read the dbgHelp only handles native frames.
Also, I tried finding information about how the .NET callstack is built but didn't find anything.
Does anybody know a link for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DbgHelp only handles native frames, but the [Managed Debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404520.aspx) is actually a native API (naturally, since you can't use managed code to debug when the managed runtime is stopped at a breakpoint).

And [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282)'s a sample.

Of particular interest will be the [ICorDebugStackWalk interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd646502.aspx).

Comment: Ok, So I can use this from a c++ program without the overhead of switching from unmanaged code to managed, right?  I think i'll try to use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233401(v=VS.80).aspx since it is supported in framework  2 as well :)